# how to implment two way sync dom using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

Can we use MutationObserver  to implement two way sync in dom, either side can make changes and same need to reflect on another side. (this is going to be used for co browsing.)

here are same libraries that made this  like
https://github.com/dvideby0/screenshare
but the problem in this is that is only implements one way sync using TreeMirror js.
client use TreeMirror (where changes are comming but not going back to server or sharer). 
server or sharing screen use TreeMirrorClient class (that listen for changes and send to another client).

is there any other library or sample code that implmented two ways sync of dom.

Comment: Two-way syncing is a much harder problem because you have to deal with the potential issue of conflicting changes. There isn't really a one-size fits all solution for HTML for that.